# threejs - morphTargets shrink other meshes in scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

Description of the problem

I have a simple box mesh with a morphTarget and a slider which adjusts the morphTargetInfluence. The morph affects the mesh as it should but it also shrinks any other mesh in the scene.

I've put together a jsfiddle (modified from the threejs morph target) example below to demo the issue. In this demo moving the slider correctly morphs the corner of the red cube but incorrectly shrinks the size of the blue cube. The cube meshes are entirely unrelated so I don't see how the morph could affect the blue cube.

https://jsfiddle.net/djmm7vv2/

```
  // JS code from jsfiddle
  var container, stats;
  var camera, scene, renderer;
  var geometry, objects;
  var mesh, mesh2;
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    // Create cameras, lights, scene, ect.
    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 15000 );
    camera.position.z = 500;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x222222 );
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x000000, 1, 15000 );
    var light1 = new THREE.PointLight( 'white', 1);
    light1.position.set( 100, 100, 100 );
    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 'white', 1);
    light2.position.set( -100, 100, 100 );
    scene.add( light1 );
    scene.add( light2 );

    // Create first mesh (red cube)
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 'red', morphTargets: true } );

    // Create 1 blend shape
    for ( var i = 0; i < 1; i ++ ) {
      var vertices = [];
      for ( var v = 0; v < geometry.vertices.length; v ++ ) {
        vertices.push( geometry.vertices[ v ].clone() );
        if ( v === i ) {
          vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].x *= 2;
          vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].y *= 2;
          vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].z *= 2;
        }
      }
      geometry.morphTargets.push( { name: "target" + i, vertices: vertices } );
    }
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    // Add second mesh (blue cube)
    var blue = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 'blue', morphTargets: true } );
    var box2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( box2, blue );
    scene.add( mesh2 );
    mesh2.position.x = 150

    // Create simple GUI slider to change morph influence on mesh (red cube)
    var params = {
      influence1: 0,
    };
    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    var folder = gui.addFolder( 'Morph Targets' );
    folder.add( params, 'influence1', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ] = value; } );
    folder.open();

    // Render it all
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...And here's the answer https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12691#issuecomment-345416590. My blue mesh material had morphTargets set to true. Changing it to false corrected the issue.

```
var blue = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 'blue', morphTargets: false } );
```

If anyone knows why this is the case I would love to know more. The documentation on MeshLambertMaterials is sparse. Maybe this has to do with keeping material textures from freaking out when the morph is applied?